# SchemaTron rule to find invalid records

Tags: xpath, schematron

I am trying to validate the following XML using the Schematron rule.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Biotic><Maul><Number>1</Number>
 <Record><Code IDREF="a1"/>
   <Detail><ItemID>1</ItemID></Detail>
   <Detail><ItemID>3</ItemID></Detail>
 </Record>
 <Record><Code IDREF="b1"/>
   <Detail><ItemID>3</ItemID></Detail>
   <Detail><ItemID>4</ItemID></Detail>
 </Record>
 <Record><Code IDREF="b1"/>
   <Detail><ItemID>4</ItemID></Detail>
   <Detail><ItemID>6</ItemID></Detail>
 </Record>
 <Record><Code IDREF="c1"/>
   <Detail><ItemID>5</ItemID></Detail>
   <Detail><ItemID>5</ItemID></Detail>
 </Record>
</Maul></Biotic>
```

And the check is  "ItemID should be unique for the given Code within the given Maul."

So as per requirement Records with Code b1 is not valid because ItemId 4 exists in both records.

Similarly, record C1 is also not valid because c1 have two nodes with itemId 5.

Record a1 is valid, even ItemID 3 exists in the next record but the code is different.

Schematron rule I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<title>Schematron validation rule</title>
<pattern id="P1">
  <rule context="Maul/Record" id="R1">
   <let name="a" value="//Detail/[./ItemID, ../Code/@IDREF]"/>
   <let name="b" value="current()/Detail/[./ItemID, ../Code/@IDREF]"/>
   <assert test="count($a[. = $b]) = count($b)">              
    ItemID should be unique for the given Code within the given Maul.
   </assert>
 </rule>
</pattern>
</schema>
```

Comment: I am testing using following online service https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schematron-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `let` values seem problematic. They will each return a `Detail` element (and all of its content including attributes, child elements, and text nodes). I'm not sure what the code inside the predicates `[./ItemID, ../Code/@IDREF]` is going to, but I think it will return all `Detail` elements that have either a child `ItemID` element or a sibling `Code` element with an `@IDREF` attribute, regardless of what the values of `ItemID` or `@IDREF` are.

I think I would change the rule/@context to ItemID, so the assert would fail once for each ItemID that violates the constraint.

Here are a rule and assert that work correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<title>Schematron validation rule</title>
<pattern id="P1">
  <rule context="Maul/Record/Detail/ItemID" id="R1">
   <assert test="count(ancestor::Maul/Record[Code/@IDREF = current()/ancestor::Record/Code/@IDREF]/Detail/ItemID[. = current()]) = 1">
    ItemID should be unique for the given Code within the given Maul.
   </assert>
 </rule>
</pattern>
</schema>
```

The assert test finds, within the ancestor `Maul`, any `Record` that has a `Code/@IDREF` that equals the `Code/@IDREF` of the `Record` that the current `ItemID` is in. At minimum, it will find one `Record` (the one that the current `ItemID` is in). Then it looks for any `Detail/ItemID` within those `Record`s that is equal to the current `ItemID`. It will find at least one (the current `ItemID`). The `count` function counts how many `ItemID`s are found. If more than one is found, the assert fails.

Thanks for the reference to https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schematron-validator! I wasn't aware of that tool.